# Find all jvm log files with "Exception" message and list the count of uniq exceptions

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a list of jvm log files that I need to search for Exception and then list the count of each unique exception .

```
04/12 02:20:45.183 00243577 000                  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException 
04/12 02:20:45.184 00243577 000                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 
04/12 02:20:45.184 00243578 000                  java.lang.RuntimeException 
04/12 02:20:45.185 00243579 000                  java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Following is the command I am using:

```
find . -name "*jvm*"|xargs grep " 000 " | grep -nc "Exception"
```

This gives me output of total exception count in each file :

```
./jvm1.104.log:1
./jvm1.108.log:1
./jvm1.128.log:2
```

How do I modify the command to get the unique exception count?

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException : 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : 1
java.lang.RuntimeException  : 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `awk` to get fifth column then `sort` and `uniq -c` will do the work

```
find . -name "*jvm*"|xargs grep " 000 "  | awk '{ print $5 }' | sort | uniq -c
```